# Getting the street address from a google maps geocode call

Tags: parsing, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am geocoding an address using google maps API, and I need to get the street address, city, state, and zip in distinct fields. Based on the documentation of the [address component types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) that are returned in the result, this is my code:

```
var address = "";
var city = "";
var state = "";
var zip = "";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputAddress}, function(results, status){
    if (status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        // loop through to get address, city, state, zip
        $.each(results[0].address_components, function(){
            switch(this.types[0]){
                case "postal_code":
                    zip = this.short_name;
                    break;
                case "street_address":
                    address = this.short_name;
                    break;
                case "administrative_area_level_1":
                    state = this.short_name;
                    break;
                case "locality":
                    city = this.short_name;
                    break;                  
            }
        });
    } else{ alert("Invalid Address"); }
});
```

However, it seems that when I enter addresses, "street_address" is not being returned; instead, it is returned as separate fields, most often "street_number" and "route", occasionally additional fields (such as "subpremise" for apt number). See [this example of a geocoding result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) in the docs.

How can I get an address variable that holds any fields related to the street address? For the example in the docs, I would want "1600 Ampitheatre Parkway".

Comment: It's work great for me! Thank you for your code @froadie :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the docs `street_address` is an *address type*, but that does not necessarily mean it's a type of *address component* - it could just be a tag used for the `types` array - returned with each of the objects in the `results` array:

> The `types[]` array within the returned result indicates the *address type*. These types may also be returned within `address_components[]` arrays to indicate the type of the particular address component.

What you probably should be doing is traversing through your `results` array first and find the one that includes a `street_address` in the `types` array. Then use that object to get the `formatted_address` attribute ([as mentioned by Aperçu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372096/1417588)). As [the doc states](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results): "the `formatted_address` is a string containing the human-readable address of this location". When the `type` is `street_address`, the `formatted_address` is equal to a `street_number + route` (followed by whatever other `address_components` are available). So you can either `split(',')` the `formatted_address` string to get the components you need - or use the `address_components` array of that particular object in the `results` array to grab the components that you need (of course doing it this way you'll need to concat the `street_number` and `route` yourself - so added logic is needed).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all address fields in a string, use the 'formatted_address' property:

**Code:**

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var fullAdressData = '';

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': inputAddress}, function(results, status){
    if (status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){

        fullAdressData = results[0].formatted_address;

    } else{ alert("Invalid Address"); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use "route" instead of "street_address"...

```
case "route":
      address = this.short_name;
      alert(address);
      break;
```